# Take Value From Cell to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm having an issue using Range.Value/Value2/Text

For Ex:
Cell A1 Contains IF Formula and resulted = Week 2

in my VBA i want to loop according to Week that contains in A1

so my code will be like:

```
Dim a as Integer
If (Range("A1").Text = "Week 2") Then
    a = 4
End if
```

using .text or .value or .value2 returns nothing. so variable a is equal zero

any idea how to take this value?

Comment: if you use value it should still read it as week 2. It could be because you haven't fully specified what book and sheet the Range you want to look at is in. When you don't specify it assumes you mean the active sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brotato says, define the range explicitly (for example):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckA1()

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Week 2" Then
        MsgBox "It is Week 2"
    End If

End Sub
```

Which would result in ...

[image: screen1]